# Parsing XML content with Flash ActionScript 3.0

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, actionscript-3, flash

I have a XML which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
- phpMyAdmin XML Dump
- version 3.5.2.2
- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
-
- Host: 127.0.0.1
- Generation Time: Dec 04, 2013 at 06:05 PM
- Server version: 5.5.27
- PHP Version: 5.4.7
-->

<pma_xml_export version="1.0">
<!--
- Database: 'tvguide.ro'
-->
<database name="tvguide.ro">
    <!-- Table tv_channels_programs -->
    <table name="tv_channels_programs">
        <column name="tv_channel_id">1</column>
        <column name="ts_on">2013-12-04 01:00:00</column>
        <column name="ts_off">2013-12-04 01:59:59</column>
        <column name="title_l0">Poveştiri adevărate</column>
    </table>
    <table name="tv_channels_programs">
        <column name="tv_channel_id">1</column>
        <column name="ts_on">2013-12-04 02:00:00</column>
        <column name="ts_off">2013-12-04 02:29:59</column>
        <column name="title_l0">Poveştiri de noapte</column>
    </table>
    <table name="tv_channels_programs">
        <column name="tv_channel_id">1</column>
        <column name="ts_on">2013-12-04 02:30:00</column>
        <column name="ts_off">2013-12-04 02:59:59</column>
        <column name="title_l0">Cancan.ro</column>
    </table>
```

The XML goes on like this for hundreds of Rows. What I am trying to achieve is this output:

> For channel 1 from 2013-12-04 01:00:00 to 1013-12-04 01:59:59 is Povestiri adevarate
>
> For channel 1 from 2013-12-04 02:00:00 to 1013-12-04 02:29:59 is Povestiri de noapte
>
> ...

Can I include also trace somehow? Thx

Comment: you should look into E4X : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e72.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it, here is the code for future reference:

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load( new URLRequest( "tv_channels_programs.xml" ) );
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete);

function handleComplete( event:Event ):void
{
    var rawXML:XML = new XML( loader.data );

    // extract all fields
    var items:XMLList = rawXML.database.table;
    //trace ("Total", items.length() );

    for each( var item:XML in items )
    {
        //trace( item.column );
    }

    var titles:XMLList = rawXML.database.table.column;
    for each( item in titles )
    {
        trace( item);
    }
}
```